# Software used to create such animations?

Tags: video, animation, flash

Check the video -
https://youtu.be/uAyPXcYick0

I'd like to know which editor could I use to create such videos? I can get the flat icons, but how do I animate those? Are there presets for such animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recreate most of the stuff in that video inside Adobe After Effects, ***if*** you have all the assets on individual pictures (layers), and not merged on top of each other.

You can easily take a layer (image file) and independently change the position, rotation, opacity, size, etc. with keyframes. If you have the body parts of a character as different files, you can position them how you'd like them by dragging and dropping, and then parenting them to one specific layer, for example, the chest. Then when you change the position of the chest, the entire body moves with it.

It would also be a good idea to have the **transparent** versions of the flat icons, so you can add a custom background, and no whitespace overlaps with other layers.

It would be a better idea to draw any characters inside AE with the shape tools so you can modify the shape of any of the body parts.

Comment: I figured out from one of the source that they used flash too. But can all of these be created just using After Effects? Thanks a lot for taking an effort in writing that answer. :)

Comment: Just rewatched the video; yes, you could most definitely do everything inside After Effects, either with assets (like pictures of the individual objects), or by drawing each object with the shape/mask tools. The character in the beginning might be a bit hard, since his different body parts are moving independently, but it's possible by animating.